# Querying Date in MySQL for month or a week from ActiveRecord in Rails 3

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So, I have a table that has two dates in it, a start and and an end date. I need to be able to query to find out all of the records that are within a certain week. So, for instance:

```
start: "2012-03-12 14:00:00", end: "2012-03-12 21:00:00"
start: "2012-03-13 14:00:00", end: "2012-03-13 21:00:00" 
start: "2012-03-14 13:00:00", end: "2012-03-14 20:00:00"
start: "2012-03-15 15:00:00", end: "2012-03-15 22:00:00"
start: "2012-03-16 14:00:00", end: "2012-03-16 21:00:00"
```

I want to return all of these records by querying (somehow) "What records fall in the week of March 11 to March 17?"

I need to do this in ActiveRecord and Rails 3.2.1. Also, I would prefer if I could do this from another model. Like this dates belong to another model, let's call it ModelA.

ModelA.dates.where(What ever I need to do)

Something like that?

Comment: Should *both* the end date and the start date be in the specified week or should *either* be in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ModelA.dates.where('start >= ? OR end <= ?', week_start, week_end)
```

Or:

```
ModelA.dates.where('start >= ? AND start <= ? AND end >= ? AND end <= ?', week_start, week_end, week_start, week_end)
```